Apply() and get() together in dataframe
I have a column with names ("name") that also might contain 2 versions of also known as (aka) e.g. "John Snow alias Aegon Targaryen" and "Tyrion Lannister @ The Imp".
Based on separator, it might be normal aka (if sep "alias"), or lqaka (low quality aka if sep "@"). I want to add them to two new separate columns ("aka" and "lqaka").
So my function is:
def get_akas(str):
delims = {"alias":"aka", "@":"lqaka"}
akas = {}
for key in delims:
    if key in str:
        akas[delims[key]] = str.split(key, 1)[1]
        return akas

Then I used apply and get together:
df["aka"] = df["name"].apply(get_akas).get("aka","")

df["lqaka"] = df["name"].apply(get_akas).get("lqaka","")

It doesn't work. I'm pretty sure the way I use apply and get is incorrect. Can anyone help before winter comes?

I think you were almost there:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["John Snow alias Aegon Targaryen", "Tyrion Lannister @ The Imp"]
})

def get_akas(s):
    delims = {"alias": "aka", "@": "lqaka"}
    akas = {'aka': None, 'lqaka': None}
    for key, value in delims.items():
        if key in s:
            akas[value] = s.split(key, 1)[1].strip()
    return akas['aka'], akas['lqaka']

df[['aka', 'lqaka']] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: get_akas(x)).apply(pd.Series)

print(df)

which will give you
                              name              aka    lqaka
0  John Snow alias Aegon Targaryen  Aegon Targaryen     None
1       Tyrion Lannister @ The Imp             None  The Imp


Thanks, works great! and also thanks for improving other things, helps a lot.
